# page navigation

Tags: javascript, javascript-remoting, pagereference

i have a visualforce page where most of front end code is in HTML / CSS / JS. We are calling controller methods using javascript remoting. Is there any option other than window.open('new_page','_parent'); to perform navigation to other page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should take a look at [Creating Visualforce Pages That Work in Mobile and Desktop](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/salesforce1/Content/vf_dev_best_practices_pages_multipurpose.htm). Here is their basic example:

```
if( (typeof sforce != 'undefined') && (sforce != null) ) {
    // Salesforce1 navigation
    sforce.one.navigateToSObject(aId);
}
else {
    // Set the window's URL using a Visualforce expression
    window.location.href = 
        '{!URLFOR($Action.Account.View, account.Id)}';
}
```

If you don't care about SalesForce1, you can just use the else portion.